# Two digit ISO week format (ww) in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I want a two digit ISO week format (ww) in Bigquery

```
"select week(date)..." //statement results in a one digit week format.
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Guido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on you business logic - you might also want to consider `%W` in addition to `%V`

Try below to see the difference

```
#standardSQL
WITH SampleDates AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS day UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-02-28' UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-12-15' 
)
SELECT
  day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%a', day) AS weekday,
  FORMAT_DATE('%V', day) AS weeknumber1,
  FORMAT_DATE('%W', day) AS weeknumber2
FROM SampleDates
ORDER BY day

day         weekday weeknumber1 weeknumber2  
2016-12-15  Thu     50          50   
2017-01-01  Sun     52          00   
2017-02-28  Tue     09          09
```

See the difference for `2017-01-01`
This is because

```
%V  The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) 
    as a decimal number (01-53).   
    If the week containing January 1 has four or more days in the new year,  
    then it is week 1; otherwise it is week 53 of the previous year,   
    and the next week is week 1.  

%W  The week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week)   
    as a decimal number (00-53).
```

Meantime, you still can have two digits in legacy SQL. Ty below

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  day,
  RIGHT(STRING(100 + WEEK(day)), 2) as weeknumber
FROM (SELECT '2017-01-01' AS day),
     (SELECT '2017-02-28' AS day),
     (SELECT '2016-12-15' AS day)
ORDER BY day
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explenation.

Answer (score 2):

With [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/), you can use the `FORMAT_DATE` function with `%V` to get the ISO week number for a date. For example,

```
#standardSQL
WITH SampleDates AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-02-28' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-12-15' AS d
)
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d) AS year,
  FORMAT_DATE('%V', d) AS iso_week
FROM SampleDates;
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that week 52 or 53 may be ambigious for some years if you use %V (01-53).
Week 52/53 may belong to previous year (if date is between January 1st-3rd in some years, e.g. 2017) or to current year (if date is at the end of December).

To specify the corresponding year you can use %G (4 digits) or %g (2 digits).

On the other hand, week 1 may also be ambigious and belong to next year (if date is at the end of December in some years, e.g. 2018) or to current year (if date is in January).

```
#standardSQL
WITH SampleDates AS (
  SELECT DATE '2015-12-31' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-01-01' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2016-12-31' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-01' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-02' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-02-28' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2017-12-31' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-01-01' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-30' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2018-12-31' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-01' AS d UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2019-01-07' AS d
)
SELECT
  d as date, 
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM d) AS year,
  FORMAT_DATE('%a', d) AS week_day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%V - %G', d) AS iso_week,
  FORMAT_DATE('%W - %G', d) AS W_G
FROM SampleDates
ORDER BY date;

Row date        year    week_day    iso_week    W_G  
  1 2015-12-31  2015    Thu         53 - 2015   52 - 2015    
  2 2016-01-01  2016    Fri         53 - 2015   00 - 2015    
  3 2016-12-31  2016    Sat         52 - 2016   52 - 2016    
  4 2017-01-01  2017    Sun         52 - 2016   00 - 2016    
  5 2017-01-02  2017    Mon         01 - 2017   01 - 2017    
  6 2017-02-28  2017    Tue         09 - 2017   09 - 2017    
  7 2017-12-31  2017    Sun         52 - 2017   52 - 2017    
  8 2018-01-01  2018    Mon         01 - 2018   01 - 2018    
  9 2018-12-30  2018    Sun         52 - 2018   52 - 2018    
 10 2018-12-31  2018    Mon         01 - 2019   53 - 2019    
 11 2019-01-01  2019    Tue         01 - 2019   00 - 2019    
 12 2019-01-07  2019    Mon         02 - 2019   01 - 2019
```

Replacing %V by %W avoids ambiguity but you will loose ISO numbers - see 2019-01-07:

```
Row date        ...     ...         iso_week    W_G 
 12 2019-01-07  ...     ...         02 - 2019   01 - 2019
```